# .htaccess unmasked on single page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been working through various .htaccess tutorials and guides to convert my dynamic URLs to flat SEO-friendly ones.

Everything is working fine, apart from one link, which seems to revert to a dynamic URL. I've tried disabling a few rules but I can't seem to solve the issue.

Example redirects

http://iforwms.com/page/home => http://iforwms.com/index.php?page=home (no problem)

**http://iforwms.com/page/blog** => **http://iforwms.com/index.php/blog?page=blog** (??)

Here is my entire .htaccess file. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this...

```
# Set Timezone
SetEnv TZ Asia/Shanghai
Options +FollowSymLinks 

# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on 

# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.iforwms\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://iforwms.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# Rewrite user URLs
RewriteRule ^page/(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

# Retrieve tagged blog posts
RewriteRule ^page/blog/(\w+)$ index.php?page=blog&tag=$1 [L]

# Retrieve single blog post
RewriteRule ^page/article/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=blog&article=$2 [L]
```

Thanks in advance,

-ifor

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `/blog/` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the 'pages' for the rewrite link, and it has somehow fixed the problem. Here's my updated .htaccess for anyone else who happens to have the same issue.

```
# Set Timezone
SetEnv TZ Asia/Shanghai
Options +FollowSymLinks 

# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on 

# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.iforwms\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://iforwms.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# Rewrite user URLs
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

# Retrieve tagged blog posts
RewriteRule ^blog/(\w+)$ index.php?page=blog&tag=$1 [L]

# Retrieve single blog post
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=blog&article=$2 [L]
```